# Limitation to xor encryption

Tags: c, xor, encryption

I am trying to encrypt a plaintext string to ecncrypted string later to use it I am again revese-encrypting it. I am using arbitrary key manually and in most of the cases I am able to get plain string back. But specially if plain text is having `"$"` then encrypted text is not being re-encrypt(decrypt) to original;

```
char * xor(char * plain_text, char * key) {
    size_t plaintext_len = strlen(plain_text);
    size_t keylen = strlen(key);

    char * encrypted = malloc(plaintext_len+1);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < plaintext_len; i++) {
        encrypted[i] = plain_text[i] ^ key[i % keylen];
    }
    encrypted[plaintext_len] = '\0';

    return encrypted;
}
```

I am new to C and hence want to know why this `'$'` character is not being displayed back. OR Is there are any limititaion while selecting a plain text and key

Thanks

PS: now '$' is not the problem still want to know worst case for xor's fails

Comment: Please don't call it encryption when you're using repeating xor with a key. You're creating a false sense of security like using a paper clip instead of a lock and calling it a safe.

Comment: @Art: with key longer than plain_text it's like one-time padd and it is perfectly ok...

Comment: Thanks . Maybe i dont have that much sense of encryption and have only option in my knowledge Actually here I want to use it as scrambled data from one application to another . So that in midway nobody can imagine what was writen there. May be paper clip/bag but data will be hidden

Comment: malloc inside function may cause memory leaks when you forgot to deallocate the memory. Please instead of malloc add the buffer to the arguments and let the caller to handle the allocation and deallocation...

Comment: There is no reason for special handling of $ character. Are you sure you have the valid input and the key is the same for "encryption" and "decryption"?

Comment: If  it is possible for the xor'ed result to be 0, then the "encrypted" string will truncate at that point.  Is the key character used for the $ equal to 0xDB?

Comment: @V-X Thanks got it was limitation from terminal while input. Still will like to know cases where xor can fail

Comment: xor won't fail. @cup has correctly pointed out, thay you may get zero inside the encoded string and your function may not be able to decode that properly. Also you may got some issues with the terminal input.

Comment: AT cup and At V-X thanks it may be the issue let me dig it out here . A lot to learn :)

Comment: @Art - it is encryption. Just a very weak encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the fundamental problem you have here is that your encryption can produce a character array that contains `'\0'` characters. That character is then treated as the terminating character when you come to decrypt. What's more, why should your key be constrained not to contain `'\0'` characters?

To solve this you do need to get your functions to work with the lengths of the arrays. You cannot rely on `strlen()` to obtain the length. I suggest that you add extra parameters to the function to allow the caller to pass in the lengths of the two character arrays.

Your functions should also receive `const char*`. So I'd have it like this:

```
char *xor(
    const char *plain_text, size_t plaintext_len, 
    const char *key, size_t keylen
) 
{
    char *encrypted = malloc(plaintext_len+1);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < plaintext_len; i++) 
        encrypted[i] = plain_text[i] ^ key[i % keylen];
    encrypted[plaintext_len] = '\0';
    return encrypted;
}
```

It's plausible that the caller can use `strlen()` to calculate the lengths of the plain text and the key. But for the decrypt operation you must remember the length of the original plain text, and pass that to the function.